# What is different between Import and require in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, require, es6-modules

I understand that `import` and `require` both can work if I want to use a class/module from another file. But I don't really know why

if I use `require ('./config.json')` will work, 
but use `import config from './config.json'` would not work.

Does this because import only accept class/module, can't work with JSON?

I also know import is working when compile, but require is working on run time.

But really confused.

Comment: you kind of answered your own question there.

Comment: This topic is non-trivial.

Answer (score -1):

These are two totally different module systems and thus don't work the same way.

- [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) is part of what referred to as "ES modules" i.e the native javascript implementation of modules brought by ES6.
- [`require`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_require), on the other hand, is the import keyword of the commonjs module system. It is still used widely today, because Node.js uses it (there was no native module system in the JavaScript spec at the time of its creation).

Have a look at both the import/export docs on the MDN and the require docs on the node.js website.